Iterating over lines in text file in Python not matching the criteria
I'm currently working with some chat messages from WhatsApp and I need to split them in a way that allows me to use them for other applications. These messages are plain text and follow a specific pattern.
Everything is going well, except for when users include new lines, such as when they send more detailed messages. This results in new lines within the message.
Thus, I require a pattern that can join these lines that do not match my desired pattern.
Currently, I'm iterating over the lines and using a REGEX pattern at the beginning of each line to determine if it's valid or not.
However, the issue I'm encountering is that I'm unable to join them properly.
The desired out put would be in the line 5 joined with next lines until the next pattern is matched.
[31/08/2020, 15:07:29] Paulo Bombinhas: Temos sim. Precisamos ver com o condomínio boulevard como vai ficar para reservar. Semana passada quando falei com eles dissseram que até então a capacidade de ocupação dos aptos está em 50% ou seja apenas 3 pessoas por apartamento
[31/08/2020, 15:08:41] Maria: Deste jeito não alugara né
[31/08/2020, 15:12:21] Paulo Bombinhas: Com essa taxa de ocupação fica bem difícil alugar. Mas acredito que para o verão já esteja normalizado
[10/09/2020, 11:04:25] Maria: Eu te passo
[11/09/2020, 10:45:21] Maria: administradora de Bens Ltda
36572992/0001-79
Caixa 104
Agência 4111
C/ C 245551-7 operação 005511
[15/09/2020, 06:36:31] Paulo Bombinhas: Bom dia Maria. Hoje vou passar o dia com a Livia para terminar o relatório e caso haja pendências já acertarmos também. Preciso entrar em contato por telefone também, me avise o melhor horário por favor.
[15/09/2020, 08:07:58] Maria: Bom dia Paulo. Que ótimo!  

This is the code I'm using:
import re

def process_chat_files(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        processed_lines = []
        pattern = r'^\[\d{2}\/'


        if not re.match(pattern, cleaned_line):
            joiner = line[-1] + line
            processed_lines.append(joiner)
        else:
            processed_lines.append(line)


    
    with open('./whats/_chat_to_join_fixed.txt', 'w') as file:
        for line in processed_lines:
            file.write(line)



Can you share your REGEX pattern, so that we can look to modify it?

Ok. Thanks. Updated the code. But it's not working because the lines become a mess.

Here is some code which will work:
import re
import os

# Regular expression pattern
pattern = r'^\[\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}, \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\].*'

# Input and output file paths
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

match_count = 0
output_string = ""

if os.path.exists(output_file):
    os.remove(output_file)

with open('input.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write('[00/00/0000, 00:00:00]\n')    # add last line needed to process the next to last line

with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if match_count > 0 and re.search(pattern, line):
            match_count = 0
            # match with match_count > 0, output line and set match_count to 0
            with open(output_file, 'a') as output:
                if output_string != "[00/00/0000, 00:00:00]":
                    output.write(output_string + "\n")
                    output_string = line
        # Check if line matches the pattern and the match_count is 0
        if match_count == 0 and re.search(pattern, line):
            match_count += 1
            # match found, save line to output string
            output_string = line

        if match_count > 0 and not re.search(pattern, line):
            # append line to output string
            output_string = output_string + " || " + line


Turns out I needed an extra clean step to remove not only empty lines, but also empty spaces between the lines that created a new index and generated an error.
After that, I created a regex match for finding the date. When I got a negative match (a line not starting with date), I took the above line that I already sent to the array processed_lines_final and addrf the current line with the negative regex in a variable (-1 index + current line). After that, I just popped the last entry into the array and replaced it with the variable.
import re

def process_chat_files(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        processed_lines = []
        processed_lines_clean = []
        processed_lines_final = []

        pattern_iphone = r'^\d{2}\/'


    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        cleaned_line = line.strip()
        processed_lines.append(cleaned_line)
    
    for index, line in enumerate(processed_lines):
        line = line.replace('\u200e', '')
        if line and not cleaned_line.isspace():
            processed_lines_clean.append(line)

    for line in processed_lines_clean:
        match = re.match(pattern_iphone, line)
        if match:
            processed_lines_final.append(line.strip())
        elif not re.match(pattern_iphone, line):
            joiner = processed_lines_final[-1] + line
            processed_lines_final.pop()
            processed_lines_final.append(joiner)
        else:
            print("Error")

    for line in processed_lines_final:
        print(line)

    with open('./paulochat_fixed.txt', 'w') as file:
        for line in processed_lines_final:
            file.write(line + '\n') 


process_chat_files('./paulochat.txt')

